# Modulo Multiplication Group - Square roots

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let $p,q$ be two distinct prime numbers with $p,q\neq 2$, and let $n=pq$.

Suppose that we have an algorithm $A$ that takes in $b \in Z_n^*$ and returns

- If $b$ is a square number: **return one of $b$'s square roots**
- Otherwise, **return nothing**

$Z_n^*$ contains all numbers between $1$ (inclusive) and $n$ that are coprime with $n$.

How may one come up with an algorithm that computes $p$ and $q$ by calling algorithm $A$ a few times?

All ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** If $\gcd(p,q)=1$, then $x^2\equiv b\pmod{pq}$ has a solution iff $x^2\equiv b\pmod{p}$ and $x^2\equiv b\pmod{q}$ have a common solution.

I have a feeling this might help you.

**Edit:** By trial and error, you could find the solutions of the equation **mod p** and **mod q** separately. And then check if either of the entries match.